# In Rails, how should I update a value in the database with ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

When the checkbox is ticked, I just want to update the  'Needed'value in the database.
And the script is list below

```
 $('td div').find('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
 $.ajax({
          type: "PUT",
          dataType: "script",
          url: '/ecs/2',
          contentType: 'application/json',
          data: JSON.stringify({ ecs:{needed:'N'}, _method:'put' })
          }).done(function( msg )
          {
          alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
          });
});
```

});
and the controller's code is standard.

```
# PATCH/PUT /ecs/1
  # PATCH/PUT /ecs/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @ec.update(ec_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @ec, notice: 'Ec was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @ec.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

The EC is the module's name, needed is the column's name. I just want to update a new value in the needed of ec with id=2 .
But right now, I always encountered the BAD REQUEST. 
I'm not sure where is the problem.

Comment: r u getting the params correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your checkbox (make it unobtrusive, it is just a quick example):

```
... onclick="$.post('/url', {omg_it_is_checked: $(this).attr('checked')})"
```

in `routes.rb`:

```
post '/url' => 'my_controller#my_action'
```

in controller:

```
def my_action
   #....
   @var = some.actions.here.with(params[:omg_it_is_checked]) #or update what you need 
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js{render layout: false}
   end
end
```

than you have to have an appropriate view `my_action.js.erb` with something like this:

```
$('#my_uniq_dom_id').html('<%= j render partial: 'new_piece_of_html' %>') #you can render nothing or flash something
```

and last we need is `_new_piece_of_html.html.erb`:

```
<div id="new_ajaxed_content"><%= @var %></div> <!-- or you can render checked checkbox, even with animation, or error message if in some reason it was not saved -->
```

voila! `div#my_uniq_dom_id` is updated with `div#new_ajaxed_content` after controller action

---

**completely different approach** - use [this](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) gem. it is simple solution for simple needs

cheers!